# Executing sql script using RODBC, loop, stored procedure, character(empty) result

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am trying to run a following query using RODBC library

```
  USE db
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
  DECLARE @table_name TABLE 
                           (id int, 
                            value int, 
                            X nvarchar(30), 
                            Y nvarchar(30), 
                            Z BIT, 
                            mth int,
                            org int)

            DECLARE @cust TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1),ck VARCHAR(100))
            insert into @cust select ck from tableX where iA = 1
            DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
            DECLARE @rowCount INT = (Select COUNT(*) FROM @cust) 
            DECLARE @return_value int

            WHILE @cnt < @rowCount
            BEGIN

            DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(100) =  (Select ck from @cust where id = @cnt);
            INSERT INTO @table_name
            EXEC    [dbo].[testProcedure]
            @nm = 6,
            @ck = @temp
            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
            END;

            SELECT * from @table_name
```

I have tried swapping variables of type TABLE to temp tables, where in case of temp tables it returns nothing while it returns a value - character(empty). Looked at similar problems and applied all suggested solutions like SET NOCOUNT ON or SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, all with no result.

The sql query passed to R is exactly same as it is for sqlserv.

```
dbhandle<- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=xxxx;database=xxxx;  Uid:xxxx; Pwd=xxxx')


query <- paste("sql query")

data2<- sqlQuery(dbhandle, query) - tried also with as.is parameter.
```

Any advice highly appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run this in SSMS? Do you have more than 1 row in tableX where iA = 1? If there is only 1 row that meets that criteria your loop will never run.

Comment: It runs absolutely fine in SSMS, getting 50k results atm.

Comment: Ouch....50k results means you are running that procedure in a loop 50k times. Would perform a lot better if you could get rid of that loop. Maybe convert that procedure to receive a table valued parameter instead. This isn't an answer to your problem but it will prevent some nasty performance problems. As for the topic at hand...we don't have anything to go on here. You posted some sql code which works. But you state that your R code doesn't get results. How about posting that code for us?

Comment: No, the iteration happens 160times - more less. Anyway, performance is not a problem here, query runs in about 60 seconds which is absolutely fine in this case. Updated the question. Thanks!